# SQLite. Insert a value depending on the value of another column

Tags: sqlite, insert, constraints

E.g., I insert a value to the column called `SALARY`. If the inserted value is greater than 1000, I'd like to insert the string HIGH to the column called `RANK` and LOW otherwise.

Can I do that using SQLite?

Comment: I don't quite understand the data structure. Are `SALARY` and `RANK` columns of the same table?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, yes, they are

Comment: Then what do you mean by "Insert a value depending on the value of another row"? Do you mean another column?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, yes. There are two columns: a column called `SALARY` and a column called `RANK`. The value in `RANK` depends on the value in `SALARY`.

Answer (score 2):

Use Trigger BEFORE INSERT and there put your logic (if bigger than 1000, put HIGH etc.). In "before" triggers you have access to data that is about to be inserted so you can check value easily. Doc: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Comment: If my trigger inserts something, there will be two rows: the one I inserted using `INSERT` and the one the trigger inserted. So I think I should update the inserted row by its ID. Is it right?